# Manifest file verification error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scoreloop

I need your help. 
I'm struggling to integrate Scoreloop with a simple Android App (a sort of "Hello World" Android app). I followed all the steps described in the scoreloopUI documentation provided by Scoreloop. To recap:

- I create a simple Android app in Eclipse;
- I imported the scoreloopUI project in Eclipse;
- I went to the properties of my simple project and I linked the scoreloopUI project as a library;
- I added `scoreloop.properties` file into the Assets folder of my simple project;
- I changed my `manifest.xml` file adding the entries described in the documentation ("Updating the Android Manifest" part);
- I changed my Activity adding `ScoreloopManagerSingleton.init(this, "whatever_your_game_secret_is");` (obviously I changed "whatever_your_game_secret_is" with my real secret).

When I run the program an Exception occurs:

```
Manifest file verification error. Please resolve any issues first!
```

Any suggestions? Thank you for helping me!

**EDIT:** This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.provascore"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
    <!-- Permission configuration required by Scoreloop -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.provascore.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Defining the ScoreloopUI activities -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.EntryScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ShowResultOverlayActivity"
            android:theme="@style/sl_dialog" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.market.MarketHeaderActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.market.MarketListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.entry.EntryListActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.post.PostOverlayActivity"
            android:theme="@style/sl_dialog" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.score.ScoreHeaderActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.score.ScoreListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserAddBuddyListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserHeaderActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserDetailListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameDetailHeaderActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameDetailListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.profile.ProfileSettingsListActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.profile.ProfileSettingsPictureListActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.LeaderboardsScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.framework.ScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.framework.TabsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the scoreloopUI project manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application>

        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.EntryScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.PostScoreOverlayActivity" android:theme="@style/sl_dialog"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ShowResultOverlayActivity" android:theme="@style/sl_dialog"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.BuddiesScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.LeaderboardsScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ChallengesScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.AchievementsScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.SocialMarketScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ProfileScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.GameItemPaymentScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.market.MarketHeaderActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.market.MarketListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.entry.EntryListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.post.PostOverlayActivity" android:theme="@style/sl_dialog"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.score.ScoreHeaderActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.score.ScoreListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserAddBuddyListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserHeaderActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserDetailListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameDetailHeaderActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameDetailListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.achievement.AchievementHeaderActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.achievement.AchievementListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.news.NewsHeaderActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.news.NewsListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengeHeaderActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengeListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengeAcceptListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengeCreateListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.profile.ProfileSettingsListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.profile.ProfileSettingsPictureListActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.payment.PaymentMethodListActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.payment.GameItemHeaderActivity"/>

        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.framework.ScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.framework.TabsActivity"/>

        <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.ProxyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>

        <activity android:name="com.boku.mobile.android.PaymentPanelActivity" 
            android:label="Paymo Panel" 
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation"  
            android:theme="@style/BokuModal"/>

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

        <activity android:name="com.zong.android.engine.web.ZongWebView" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.zong.mobile.PAYMENT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <provider android:name="com.zong.android.engine.provider.ZongPersistanceProvider" android:authorities="com.zong.provider.persistence"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your manifest. since the logcat says "one of these is missing".

Comment: Please post the manifest.  Not related, but do you understand the dangers of using the `android:configChanges="orientation"` hack?

Comment: @Simon-- this is not related to a question but  Can you give a link to a tutorial or a blog abt it ...

Comment: @BhanuKaushik http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html.  You add this, the crash (which exists because the activity life cycle code is not properly done) goes away and the developer thinks it's OK.  However, the other reasons why your activity is destroyed and recreated still cause a crash.  If your app doesn't crash without it, then consider adding it only if you will take care of all resource reloading - which is what Android does for you and should be (99% of the time) what happens.

Comment: I've just added my manifest file and the scoreloopUI project manifest file to the main post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the fact that in my manifest file there weren't some entries: reading the scoreloopUI documentation you can find the "Updating the Android Manifest" section. In this section some entries are provided, but they are not enough! These are the provided entries:

```
<!-- Defining the ScoreloopCore activities -->
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.core.ui.ProxyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
 <!-- Note: you may need to add more entries here for the payment methods you want to use. -->

 <!-- Defining the ScoreloopUI activities -->
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.EntryScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ShowResultOverlayActivity" android:theme="@style/sl_dialog"/>

 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.market.MarketHeaderActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.market.MarketListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.entry.EntryListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.post.PostOverlayActivity" android:theme="@style/sl_dialog"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.score.ScoreHeaderActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.score.ScoreListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserAddBuddyListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserHeaderActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserDetailListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.user.UserListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameDetailHeaderActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameDetailListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.game.GameListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.profile.ProfileSettingsListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.profile.ProfileSettingsPictureListActivity"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.LeaderboardsScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.framework.ScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
 <activity android:name="com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.framework.TabsActivity"/>
```

Searching on the web, I found this [scoreloop class](https://code.google.com/p/angdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/ui/StandardScoreloopManager.java?r=285) (StandardScoreloopManager). At the bottom of this class there's a function that checks the user's manifest file. Some required entries aren't in the documentation above:

```
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.achievement.AchievementHeaderActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.achievement.AchievementListActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.news.NewsHeaderActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.news.NewsListActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengeHeaderActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengeListActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengeAcceptListActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengeCreateListActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.component.challenge.ChallengePaymentActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.BuddiesScreenActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ChallengesScreenActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.AchievementsScreenActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.SocialMarketScreenActivity"
"com.scoreloop.client.android.ui.ProfileScreenActivity"
```

Adding these entries in the manifest file solves the issue. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing. Did you check isLibrary option for scoreloopUI project.
Select project scoreloopUI, right click, goto Properties --> Android -->at the bottom of android menu you will see isLibrary option tick so that you can it as android library project in other projects